# How to collect a single property in a list of objects?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, reflection, code-generation

Is it possible to create an extension method to return a single property or field in a list of objects?

Currently I have a lot of functions like the following.

```
public static List<int> GetSpeeds(this List<ObjectMotion> motions) {
    List<int> speeds = new List<int>();
    foreach (ObjectMotion motion in motions) {
        speeds.Add(motion.Speed);
    }
    return speeds;
}
```

This is "hard coded" and only serves a single property in a single object type. Its tedious and I'm sure there's a way using LINQ / Reflection to create an extension method that can do this in a generic and reusable way. Something like this:

```
public static List<TProp> GetProperties<T, TProp>(this List<T> objects, Property prop){
    List<TProp> props = new List<TProp>();
    foreach (ObjectMotion obj in objects) {
        props.Add(obj.prop??);
    }
    return props;
}
```

Apart from the easiest method using LINQ, I'm also looking for the fastest method. Is it possible to use code generation (and Lambda expression trees) to create such a method at runtime? I'm sure that would be faster than using Reflection.

Comment: You function could be written as "motions.Select( motion => motion.Speed)". That's not exactly generic, but for a start it's a lot shorter than writing and calling a method each time.

Comment: Only calling my method may be faster. (LINQ is usually slower than non-generic code)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do:

```
public static List<TProp> GetProperties<T, TProp>(this IEnumerable<T> seq, Func<T, TProp> selector)
{
    return seq.Select(selector).ToList();
}
```

and use it like:

```
List<int> speeds = motions.GetProperties(m => m.Speed);
```

it's questionable whether this method is better than just using `Select` and `ToList` directly though.

Answer (score 7):

It is, no reflection needed:

```
List<int> values = motions.Select(m=>m.Speed).ToList();
```

Comment: How do I create an extension method to do this? I don't want to write this snippet everytime. And how do I use code generation to create the fastest method?

Comment: public static List<O> GetValues<T,O>(this List<T> target, Func<T,O> selector){ return target.Select(selectoror);}

Comment: but no need to make a function, Select *is* a function already

Answer (score 1):

A for loop would be the fastest I think, followed closely by linq (minimal overhead if you don't do use closures). I can't image any other mechanism would be any better than that.

You could replace the `List<int>` with a `int[]` or initialize the list with a certain capacity. That would probably do more to speed up your code than anything else (though still not much).